# Unable to start dashDB Local on RedHat

Tags: centos, dashdb

After successfully create a container from dashDB Local image, I try to start the dashDB environment on a redhat machine :

```
[root@lat131 tmp]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
```

Here are the errors I get when I run followings commands:

```
[root@lat131 tmp]# docker start dashDB

dashDB

[root@lat131 tmp]# docker logs --follow dashDB

...

[347385.874434] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: dashDB Local configuration: SMP

[347389.462970] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: Checking if dashDB initialize has been done previously ...

[347397.566534] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: dashDB stack is NOT initialized yet.

[347398.034134] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: ##################################################################

[347398.034383] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: Running dashDB prerequisite checks on node: lat131.labo.infotel.com

[347398.034544] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: ##################################################################

[347398.061163] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: ##################################################################

[347398.061504] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: Prerequisite check -- Platform Check

[347398.061654] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: ##################################################################

[347398.061804] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: Traceback (most recent call last):

[347398.061947] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: File "/usr/lib/prerequisites_check.py", line 504, in <module>

[347398.062106] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: if not chk_platform():

[347398.062252] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: File "/usr/lib/prerequisites_check.py", line 184, in chk_platform

[347398.062391] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: with open('/tmp/.build_version') as lines:**

[347398.062530] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/.build_version'

[347398.068359] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: #####################################################################

[347398.068540] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: Prerequisite check failed.

[347398.068688] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: Examine the relevant messages printed to the console window when

[347398.068830] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: the prerequisite check was running and take the required corrective

[347398.068980] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: actions before attempting to set up dashDB.

[347398.069135] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: Exiting the dashDB deployment.

[347398.069283] start_dashDB_local.sh[193]: #####################################################################

 Stopping The entrypoint script for initializing dashDB local...
```

The same dashDB docker image has been used on another Linux system (OpenSuse 42.2), and there is no issue when starting dashDB Local.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing ?

```
docker stop dashDB
docker rm dashDB
rm -rf /mnt/clusterfs/*
docker run -d -it --privileged=true --net=host --name=dashDB 
-v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/bludata0 
-v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/blumeta0 ibmdashdb/local:latest-linux
```

Something is wrong with your dashDB container. I saw this on one of my centos servers but there were 2 others that worked with no issue. If this doesn't work you may need to clean the docker dashDB image and start the download over. You can only clean the image by doing a

```
docker stop dashDB
service stop docker
service start docker
rm -rf /var/run/docker
docker rm dashDB
rm -rf /mnt/clusterfs/*
docker run -d -it --privileged=true --net=host --name=dashDB 
-v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/bludata0 
-v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/blumeta0 ibmdashdb/local:latest-linux
```